# How to use serdev driver in am335x?

Tags: linux-kernel, serial-port, linux-device-driver, beagleboneblack

I have one beaglebone black which has am335x processor and uses linux kernel 5.4. I want to just send and receive data on Tx Rx at uart4 using serdev driver(not use /dev/tty layer). so I find one example code which is drivers/iio/chemical/pms7003.c But this example based on slave sensors and it is not work in my case. so anyone helps me how to use uart using serdev driver to Write and read data on the Tx Rx line without a slave device?

Comment: What do you mean by _write and read data on the Tx Rx line without a slave device_? Are you sending data to an outer space?

Comment: Not in space , I just want to see data in TX Rx bus same as we check AT command on putty application

Comment: Then create a "fake" hardware representation in the software. Imagine an external loop back (Tx <--> Rx short circuit), try to write a driver for it.

Comment: Ok thanks but how to write driver ? Can you explain me or any example??

Comment: You already have the example, copy it under a new name, change “compatible” string in it, remove all specific hardware communication. This will be a good base to start with.

Comment: The main purpose of serdev is to support kernel drivers for serial connected devices, but since you do not seem to have a specific type of serial device in mind, I don't know why you'd want to use serdev.